# LINQ Get Average values from IQueryable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to LINQ and I need to write a LINQ query that returns each project's grade, called `note`t also the average of all `notes`.
Here is the query I have:

```
`var query = _context.Set<EvaluationResult>()
                                .Include(x => x.RatingLevel)
                                .Include(x => x.Skill)
                                .Include(x => x.Evaluation)
                                    .ThenInclude(y => y.Project)
                                        .ThenInclude(z => z.ProjectRatingLevels)
                                            .ThenInclude(a => a.RatingLevel)
                                .Include(y => y.Evaluation.Project)
                                    .ThenInclude(y => y.Degree)
                                .Where(x => x.Evaluation.Project.DegreeId == QueriedDegreeId)
                                .GroupBy(i => new { project = i.Evaluation.Project })
                                .Select(g => new
                                {
                                    project = g.Select(y => y.Evaluation.Project.Label)
                                               .Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),

                                    note = Math.Round(((g.Sum(y => (double)y.Skill.Weight * (double)y.RatingLevel.Rate) /
                                                        g.Sum(y => (double)y.RatingLevel.Rate)) * 100) /
                                                        (double)g.Key.project.ProjectRatingLevels
                                                                 .Select(z => z.RatingLevel.Rate)
                                                                 .Max(), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
                                });
```

Here is the result:

```
[
    {
        "project": "Projet 1",
        "note": 42.86
    },
    {
        "project": "Projet 2",
        "note": 41.67
    },
    {
        "project": "Projet 3",
        "note": 46.67
    }
]
```

What I want is to add another value, `average`, which is just the Average of all "note" values, like so (the asterisks are just for emphasis):

```
[
    {
        "project": "Projet 1",
        "note": 42.86,
        **"average": 43.73**
    },
    {
        "project": "Projet 2",
        "note": 41.67,
        **"average": 43.73**
    },
    {
        "project": "Projet 3",
        "note": 46.67,
        **"average": 43.73**
    }
]
```

---

**MY PROBLEM**

I'm stuck trying to calculate an Average of all the returned `note`s. I have no idea how to proceed. I tried to add an `average` key in my `Select` after `note` and `project` that reused the `note` query,  like this:

```
average = g.Average(Math.Round(((g.Sum(... etc
```

But this gives me type errors: `CS1929  'IGrouping<<anonymous type: Project project>, EvaluationResult>' does not contain a definition for average 'Average'`. So I'm at an utter loss of what to do.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Am I missing something, like the need to use a `Key` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your goal to do it all in one query ?

The only possible Resultset, with Aggregate and the Aggregated Items, is a GroupBy.
If you want to aggregate all, you want only one group, so you have to have a fictive key,the same one for each item

So Append:

```
 .GroupBy(x => 1) /* makes one group for all, all have the same key */
 .Select(g => new { average = g.Average(x => x.notes), items = g.Select(x => x)});
```

But this is really Forcing the SQL-Server to do the average. You Manifest the items in your memory anyway. So you can also take your existing Resultset, manifested with ToList or ToArray and just compute

```
 var result = <yourquery>.ToList();
 double average = result.Average(x => x.notes);
```

The only difference is, this is done on your CPU, not on the SQL-Server.

Comment: I want it to be done in a single query because it's an Azure Function so it's easier for me to convert the result to a single object. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you!